# Difference between Vaishnava agamas and tantra

Tags: vishnu, tantra, agamas

There are two main agamas according to which Vishnu temple puja is performed, namely, Vaikhanasa agama and Pancharatra agama. In addition to these modes of worship, Vishnu temples in the West coast, particularly, Kerala, follow tantric way of worship. How does the tantric way of worship differ from the other two Vaishnava agamas in terms of rituals and philosophy?